# How to get the backslash symbol to show up?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, backslash

I keep on getting a yen symbol whenever I press the backslash key. Is there a way to change this? I'm using python by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, but i changed the font in Python IDLE away from the default Meiryo and it fixed it. In IDLE go to Options > Configure IDLE, then in the 'Fonts/Tabs' tab, change the font face to something like Arial. This worked for me.

Comment: Using courier as the font is often recommended as it is monospace, meaning all the characters will take up the same space, and most coding environments work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been over a year since this question has been asked. I was in your position and kind of ignored the problem, but I finally reached a solution that fixes it. It has to do with certain programs (including cmd.exe) using UNICODE. I was working with java and this problem was heeding progress in what I was doing.

This solution works in Windows 10, the method most likely exists for older versions such as 7 or 8 or 8.1

1) Go to language settings in Control Panel

2) Go to the 'Change date, time, or number formats' link on the left.

3) Go to the administrative tab

4) In the section for 'Language for non-Unicode programs,' it was set to Japanese for me. Since I live in Canada, I appropriately selected English (Canada)

5) Reboot your computer

6) To test this: open cmd.exe and look at the directory present. It should no longer be yen symbols, now backslashes.